# How can I get a dynamically refreshing sheet name list in excel online? Since its online I cant use vba/macros

Tags: excel, office-scripts

I tried indicated scripts, the following one works on the desktop version:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  let sheetNames = workbook.getWorksheets().map(sh => [sh.getName()])
  let output_sheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet2")
  output_sheet.getRange("A:A").clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.all)
  output_sheet.getRange("A1").getResizedRange(sheetNames.length - 1, 0).setValues(sheetNames)
}
```

once I migrate the file online the sheet names are not refreshing or dynamically changing.

What would be the solution for that?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Let’s start there.

Comment: Are you just trying to dynamically reference the first sheet?                                            let sheet = workbook.getWorksheets()[0];